# Typo3 MM Relation

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-6.2.x

I have an n:m relation between two tables so typo3 extension builder generated an mm table for me.

so now I want to add an relation between those two tables?

one table is called pruefling and one is called fach

and the mm table is called fach_pruefling_mm

i tried to this:

```
$fach->setMatrikelnr($pruefling->getUid());
```

extension builder looks like this:
[image]

**UPDATE:**
Fach Model

```
class Fach extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\DomainObject\AbstractEntity {

/**
 * fachnr
 *
 * @var string
 * @validate NotEmpty
 */
protected $fachnr = '';

/**
 * fachname
 *
 * @var string
 * @validate NotEmpty
 */
protected $fachname = '';

/**
 * pruefer
 *
 * @var string
 * @validate NotEmpty
 */
protected $pruefer = '';

/**
 * notenschema
 *
 * @var string
 * @validate NotEmpty
 */
protected $notenschema = '';

/**
 * modulnr
 *
 * @var string
 * @validate NotEmpty
 */
protected $modulnr = '';

/**
 * matrikelnr
 *
 * @var \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage<\ReRe\Rere\Domain\Model\Pruefling>
 */
protected $matrikelnr = NULL;

/**
 * Returns the fachnr
 *
 * @return string $fachnr
 */
public function getFachnr() {
    return $this->fachnr;
}

/**
 * Sets the fachnr
 *
 * @param string $fachnr
 * @return void
 */
public function setFachnr($fachnr) {
    $this->fachnr = $fachnr;
}

/**
 * Returns the fachname
 *
 * @return string $fachname
 */
public function getFachname() {
    return $this->fachname;
}

/**
 * Sets the fachname
 *
 * @param string $fachname
 * @return void
 */
public function setFachname($fachname) {
    $this->fachname = $fachname;
}

/**
 * Returns the pruefer
 *
 * @return string $pruefer
 */
public function getPruefer() {
    return $this->pruefer;
}

/**
 * Sets the pruefer
 *
 * @param string $pruefer
 * @return void
 */
public function setPruefer($pruefer) {
    $this->pruefer = $pruefer;
}

/**
 * Returns the notenschema
 *
 * @return string $notenschema
 */
public function getNotenschema() {
    return $this->notenschema;
}

/**
 * Sets the notenschema
 *
 * @param string $notenschema
 * @return void
 */
public function setNotenschema($notenschema) {
    $this->notenschema = $notenschema;
}

/**
 * __construct
 */
public function __construct() {
    //Do not remove the next line: It would break the functionality
    $this->initStorageObjects();
}

/**
 * Initializes all ObjectStorage properties
 * Do not modify this method!
 * It will be rewritten on each save in the extension builder
 * You may modify the constructor of this class instead
 *
 * @return void
 */
protected function initStorageObjects() {
    $this->matrikelnr = new \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage();
}

/**
 * Returns the modulnr
 *
 * @return string $modulnr
 */
public function getModulnr() {
    return $this->modulnr;
}

/**
 * Sets the modulnr
 *
 * @param string $modulnr
 * @return void
 */
public function setModulnr($modulnr) {
    $this->modulnr = $modulnr;
}

public function getMatrikelnr() {
    return $this->matrikelnr;
}

/**
 * @param $matrikelnr
 */
public function setMatrikelnr($matrikelnr) {
    $this->matrikelnr = $matrikelnr;
}

}
```

Comment: Also have a look at the example by @lorenz in http://stackoverflow.com/a/26746960/160968 which might be helpful in your project

Comment: not really ... he talks about 1:n ... but i have a n:m relation

Comment: If I remember correctly, the solution uses a n:m relation for a 1:n purpose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De facto you need to use methods `addMatrikelnr(...)` and `removeMatrikelnr(...)` for adding and remving relations, they are generated by Builder in `Fach` model.

Take a look at a `setMatrikelnr` method in the model it takes a collection not single object as a param.

There's typical set of methods for `m:n` relation:

```
<?php
namespace ReRe\Rere\Domain\Model;

class Fach extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\DomainObject\AbstractEntity {

    /**
     * matrikelnr
     *
     * @var \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage<\ReRe\Rere\Domain\Model\Pruefling>
     */
    protected $matrikelnr = NULL;

    /**
     * __construct
     */
    public function __construct() {
        //Do not remove the next line: It would break the functionality
        $this->initStorageObjects();
    }

    /**
     * Initializes all ObjectStorage properties
     * Do not modify this method!
     * It will be rewritten on each save in the extension builder
     * You may modify the constructor of this class instead
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function initStorageObjects() {
        $this->matrikelnr = new \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage();
    }

    /**
     * Adds a Pruefling
     *
     * @param \ReRe\Rere\Domain\Model\Pruefling $matrikelnr
     * @return void
     */
    public function addMatrikelnr(\ReRe\Rere\Domain\Model\Pruefling $matrikelnr) {
        $this->matrikelnr->attach($matrikelnr);
    }

    /**
     * Removes a Pruefling
     *
     * @param \ReRe\Rere\Domain\Model\Pruefling $matrikelnrToRemove The Pruefling to be removed
     * @return void
     */
    public function removeMatrikelnr(\ReRe\Rere\Domain\Model\Pruefling $matrikelnrToRemove) {
        $this->matrikelnr->detach($matrikelnrToRemove);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the matrikelnr
     *
     * @return \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage<\ReRe\Rere\Domain\Model\Pruefling> $matrikelnr
     */
    public function getMatrikelnr() {
        return $this->matrikelnr;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the matrikelnr
     *
     * @param \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage<\ReRe\Rere\Domain\Model\Pruefling> $matrikelnr
     * @return void
     */
    public function setMatrikelnr(\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage $matrikelnr) {
        $this->matrikelnr = $matrikelnr;
    }

}
```

Comment: don't have add Matrikelnr function ... `Call to undefined method ReRe\Rere\Domain\Model\Fach::addMatrikelnr()`

Comment: How about your Fach model have it these methods ?

Comment: no not really .. extension builder haven't created it 

I posted the model code in my question

Comment: Weird, which version of builder do you use ? in edit I sent you code generated by latest builder

Comment: i use 6.2.0 ... Thanks then I try this 

do I have to make changes on TCA config? as well?

Comment: Simple tip: just create ext `rere2` with missing parts (you don't even install it) so you can compare your current state with new one and copy all missing things. After `rere99` you'll know what's required for each kind of field and/or relation

Comment: I've tried it now .. so I don't get an error any more ... but a relation isn't set yet ... how can I figure out whats going wrong?

Am I right that wenn I set a Pruefling with the addMatrikelnr on Fach there should be generated an entry in tx_rere_fach_pruefling_mm?

Comment: huh, cache for 99% ... sometimes you need to clear it quite agresively to make  changes working... (install tool clear system cache) + removing content of `typo3temp/Cache` folder usually helps

Comment: no I think something in the controller ... chache was clean bevor :)
thank you alot!