# TYPO3 make ExtbaseGuide example working, get set category

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-6.2.x, typo3-7.6.x

I followed the '[Creating an Extbase extension](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseGuide/Extbase/FirstExtbaseExtension.html)' in the TYPO3 documentation and build the Product Overview, all working fine.

The next step teaches '[Extending an Extbase extension](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseGuide/Extbase/ExtendExtbaseExtension.html)' and also that works but the last step changes the TCA in order to select stored categories rather then add them inline ...

The list displays the selection possibility with the created categories and I can select them but they do not save, if I check the db the category is saved but it does not show up in the backend, and typo3 does not recognize the category saved in the field ...

can anyone give the final steps needed to make it work ... (I already installed, dis-installed, cleared cache, cleaned with install tool etc. multiple times...)

this is my tca:

```
/* original working inline code
        'categories' => [
            'exclude' => 1,
            'label' => 'LLL:EXT:productoverview/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tx_productoverview_domain_model_product.categories',
            'config' => [
                'type' => 'inline',
                'foreign_table' => 'tx_productoverview_domain_model_category',
                'foreign_field' => 'product',
                'maxitems' => 9999,
                'appearance' => [
                    'collapseAll' => 0,
                    'levelLinksPosition' => 'top',
                    'showSynchronizationLink' => 1,
                    'showPossibleLocalizationRecords' => 1,
                    'showAllLocalizationLink' => 1
                ],
            ],

        ],
suggested category selection */
        'categories' => [
          'exclude' => 0,
          'label' => 'LLL:EXT:productoverview/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xml:tx_productoverview_domain_model_product.categories',
          'config' => [
            'type' => 'select',
            'renderType' => 'selectMultipleSideBySide',
            'foreign_table' => 'tx_productoverview_domain_model_category',
            'foreign_field' => 'product',
            'maxitems'      => 9999,
          ],
        ],

    ],
];
```

**update:** I found [this answer of 2 years](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26733567/typo3-extbase-irre-add-existing-records-with-foreign-selector) ago which gives an error in v7.6.14 but explains a lot, I still hope to have a much simpler answer here ...

Comment: Do you have created the `foreign_table`?

Comment: can you please display your tca code?

Comment: @RenéPflamm ... I did only what given in the tutorial you mean `'foreign_table' => 'tx_productoverview_domain_model_category'`

Comment: @VivekParmar the whole code ? that's long ... its exactly from the documentation, but I post if you want ...

Comment: no just some portion of 'category'.

Comment: @VivekParmar i suspect it being more a matter of some configuration in the model of products, the example probably worked in TYPO3 v6 ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did try the solution of j4k3 (because also other experienced developers suggested it) but I could not make it work on my localhost and never found out why (still interested in that, I run xampp on windows 7 pro) ...

Eventually I did find a solution that worked for me that is very simple:
In the current extension builder you have the option to select the **relation type** from a select list,

I left this (never being mentioned in the ExtbaseGuide) to 1:n because that is the actual needed relation, but now I used m:n and my trouble vanished, the builder automatically creates an extra MM relation table and the full TCA code, it works straight after the extension is saved by the builder ...

Comment: This is the only solution worked for me. Still the relation is wrong. Should be 1:n and not m:n! But only worked with m:n relation for me!

Comment: @Inoir you can fix that in the TCA ... if you ask it in a separate question I'll show you the example ...

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem a few days ago, when updating an old project. What fixed the problem for me, was to define a renderType in addition to type=select:  https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/Reference/Columns/Select/Index.html#rendertype

Comment: makes sense but for me it doesn't work, I did uninstall, cleared all cache and cleaned, how did you debug ? maybe that helps me

Comment: This is, sadly, one of many places where TYPO3 lacks any means of debugging. No error message, no log, nothing. It either works, or doesn't, I guess. Have you tried to flush the configuration cache files manually? They're located in typo3temp/Cache/Code/cace_core/*.php

Comment: Yep, no use, i did see the changes while checking the renderType, from time to time I get `1: These fields of record 1 in table "tx_productoverview_domain_model_product" have not been saved correctly: categories! The values might have changed due to type casting of the database.`

Comment: Well? What type does your categories field have?

Comment: [did you see this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26733567/typo3-extbase-irre-add-existing-records-with-foreign-selector) , do you really have the 1:n relation (multiple categories for 1 product) with that simple correction ...

Comment: I'd love that to be true, but I tried a lot by now and it won't work for me ... if you want I send you my 19kb extension, and you try ...